# How to remove a specific jar file from libs folder while packaging application in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

How to remove a specific jar file from libs folder while packaging application in Android.

So for example if I have a jar named xyz.jar in libs folder and while building the Android application I would like to remove that file which generates my AAR file

I saw a couple of posts where "exclude" is used in the build.gradle file but that didn't help me out

Comment: If the library required for compiling or can it also be excluded for compiling?

Comment: It can be excluded for compiling

Answer (score 0):

Check your app's `build.gradle` file you will find a line like this that is responsible for including the jar file in the libs directory:

```
api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

You can simply clone and modify it, so that it does not match the library you want to exclude:

```
api fileTree(include: ['a*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
api fileTree(include: ['b*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Or you even explicitly name the libraries you want to include:

```
api fileTree(include: ['lib1.jar'], dir: 'libs')
api fileTree(include: ['lib2.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```